# Can we use "around about" like this?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, prepositions

Can we use "around about" together as in the following sentence?

> The building was built around about 2 years ago.

Comment: I suppose you can but stylistically it is unnecessary. I would say, *The building was built about 2 years ago.*  The inclusion of 'around' doesn't add anything.

Answer (score 2):

'Round about' (the initial *a-* is usually dropped) in the sense 'approximately' is a strictly colloquial use, and should be avoided in most formal writing.

There is also a more conventionally spatial use of this double preposition to describe a path of motion:

> We wandered round about the zoo til it closed.

When this sense is used as an intransitive the two prepositions are usually joined with *and*, and the initial *a-* is usually restored:

> We've just been driving, nowhere in particular, just around and about.

There are also a noun and an adjective, written ‹roundabout›, with several senses you can look up in a dictionary.

Comment: It must be a magic round about. It's made an 'l' disappear.

Comment: I dismiss it as a needless expense under the austerity budget.

Comment: Thanks, you have helped me clarify an edit in this question [Why does an oscilloscope show a different voltage from a signal generator?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/117806/why-does-an-oscilloscope-show-a-different-voltage-from-a-signal-generator): `Testing other amplitudes, it is not always precisely two to one, but it is round about that ratio.`

Answer (score 0):

'Around' and 'about' are synonyms. Not only is using both redundant, but it's silly: you you would would not not double double words words in other sentences, right? :)

Fun fact: a 'roundabout' is a traffic circle.